# Dump generate backup inserts in wrong order

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I am using Spring JPA to create tables in Postgres database. I have defined relations between parent and children with this annotation on parent entity:

```
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
```

Next I have tables like these:

**PARENT_TABLE** (id, created)

**CHILD_A_TABLE** (some_attr0, some_attr1)

**CHILD_B_TABLE** (some_attr2, some_attr3)

So when I click on db > backup and choose generate data with option column inserts, Postgres generate data in this order:

1. CHILD_A_TABLE inserts
2. CHILD_B_TABLE inserts
3. PARENT_TABLE inserts

But I need that PARENT_TABLE inserts will be first. Also is problem with another tables. If table has reference on another with foreign key, first are created inserts with reference on table doesn't contain data yet.

Is it possible to fix, and set Postgres to generate tables  inserts in correct order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pg-dump` generates dump so you would restore all data and AFTER all data completed it creates indexes and constraints. You can't grant the order of inserts. Imagine you have a `table_a.b_id` referencing `table_b.id` and `table_b.a_id` referencing `table_a.id`. You just can't insert any row unless you disable FK (unless you have deferrable constraints and do it in transaction - but `pg_dump` does not provide such functionality)